# Arm swing with ridged humanoid

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

On a rigged humanoid, I am testing swinging the right arm by manipulating the rotation of the shoulder joint.
In my code, you see 4 methods that give different end positions of the arm. Can anyone explain why?

When I choose method=1: the arms goes quickly in one step from its correct end position to its final position. The final position is however totally wrong.
Method=2: Again in one step to the final position. The final position is now correct
Method=3: The arm swings slowly to its final position, which has a small error (about 1 degree)
Method=4: the arm swings quickly to the end position, with a greater error (several degrees)

```
void Start()
    {

       shoulderR_AngleBegin = new Vector3(37.418f, 7.976f, -17.495f);
       shoulderR_AngleEnd = new Vector3(-6.643f, -30.957f, -80.09f);
       angle = shoulderR_AngleBegin;        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        int method = 4;
        float x, y, z;
        x = this.shoulderR_AngleBegin.x;
        y = this.shoulderR_AngleBegin.y;
        z = this.shoulderR_AngleBegin.z;

        if(angle.x > this.shoulderR_AngleEnd.x || angle.y > this.shoulderR_AngleEnd.y || angle.z > this.shoulderR_AngleEnd.z)
        {           
            if(method==1)
            {
                this.angle = this.angle + (this.shoulderR_AngleEnd - this.shoulderR_AngleBegin);
            }
            else if(method==2)
            {
                this.angle.x = this.angle.x + (this.shoulderR_AngleEnd.x - this.shoulderR_AngleBegin.x);
                this.angle.y = this.angle.y + (this.shoulderR_AngleEnd.y - this.shoulderR_AngleBegin.y);
                this.angle.z = this.angle.z + (this.shoulderR_AngleEnd.z - this.shoulderR_AngleBegin.z);
            }
            else if(method==3)
            {
                this.angle.x = this.angle.x + (this.shoulderR_AngleEnd.x - this.shoulderR_AngleBegin.x) * Time.deltaTime;
                this.angle.y = this.angle.y + (this.shoulderR_AngleEnd.y - this.shoulderR_AngleBegin.y) * Time.deltaTime;
                this.angle.z = this.angle.z + (this.shoulderR_AngleEnd.z - this.shoulderR_AngleBegin.z) * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else if (method==4)
            {
                this.angle.x = this.angle.x + (this.shoulderR_AngleEnd.x - this.shoulderR_AngleBegin.x) * Time.deltaTime * 8.0f;
                this.angle.y = this.angle.y + (this.shoulderR_AngleEnd.y - this.shoulderR_AngleBegin.y) * Time.deltaTime * 8.0f;
                this.angle.z = this.angle.z + (this.shoulderR_AngleEnd.z - this.shoulderR_AngleBegin.z) * Time.deltaTime * 8.0f;
            }  
        }

        this.ShoulderR.transform.localEulerAngles = angle;
    }
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it is to be able to have the arm do different things. How you have it now, you are hard coding in which method to use at

```
int method = 4;
```

making the other methods obsolete.

If you are asking specifically why the different methods produce a different end position, that is due to the code within each option. Method one uses the angle in general to set the position. It doesn't bother with the components of the angle.

All the other methods set each axis of the angle (or it could be setting the xyz positions which set the angle. I can only guess based on the name), but they use a different function to determine that value. You can see that each method ads in a value to multiply the last method's value by. (they add * some value for each method after method2)

```
this.ShoulderR.transform.localEulerAngles = angle;
```

Then uses the angles given to move the arm.

If you are still unsure about why it does what it does, it would be helpful to look up information on angles in 3-d coordinate systems. Specifically look at Cartesian coordinate systems as that is what the code is using from what I can see. An introduction to physics textbook should have some useful information on it. If not then check intermediate level books. I can not remember when we started on it exactly as I have an applied Psychics degree but I am not a professor.